# Why is $n \exp (-\frac{2m}{n-2}) \ge e^{-w}$?

Tags: asymptotics

Here $m=\frac{1}{2}n(\log n + w(n))$. The full claim is that

$$\left(1-o(1)\right) n \exp \bigg(-\frac{2m}{n-2}\bigg) \ge (1-o(1)) e^{-w}$$

but am I'm having trouble seeing why.

Edit:
\begin{align*}
\left(1-o(1)\right) n \exp \bigg(-\frac{2m}{n-2}\bigg) 
&= \left(1-o(1)\right) n \exp \bigg(-\frac{n(\log n + w(n))}{n-2}\bigg) \\
&= \left(1-o(1)\right) n \exp \bigg(-\left(1+\frac{2}{n-2}\right)\left(\log n + w(n)\right)\bigg) \\
&= \left(1-o(1)\right) n \exp \bigg(-\log n\bigg)\exp \bigg(\frac{-2 \log n}{n-2}\bigg) \exp \bigg(-w(n)\bigg) \exp \bigg(-\frac{2 w(n)}{n-2}\bigg)\\
&= \left(1-o(1)\right) n n^{-1}n^{\frac{-2}{n-2}} \exp \bigg(-w(n)\bigg) \exp \bigg(-\frac{2 w(n)}{n-2}\bigg)\\
&= \left(1-o(1)\right) n^{\frac{-2}{n-2}} \exp \bigg(-w(n)\bigg) \exp \bigg(-\frac{2 w(n)}{n-2}\bigg)\\
\end{align*}

and this gives the desired result because $n^{\frac{-2}{n-2}} \ge 1$ and $\exp \bigg(-\frac{2 w(n)}{n-2}\bigg) \ge 1$ if $w =o(n)$?

Comment: It's true only is $w(n)=o(n)$. Just plug in expression for $m$ and decompose $\frac n{n-2}=1+\frac 2{n-2}$.

Comment: I edited my answer using your suggestion. Can you check if my work makes sense?

Comment: Almost. $n^{\frac{-2}{n-2}}=1-o(1)$ and the other term the same.